# How to deal with huge amount of categorical data in Machine Learning using Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding, catboost

I have a dataset of cars with 100000 rows. The column is 'Manufacturer' which is an important aspect of the output, so I can't drop it. How should I deal with this problem?

Comment: You still haven't really described the problem? What are you facing right now? Long training time? Memory leaks? For large datasets, maybe consider what you want your ML to do and then see if you can partition it or use sampling etc. Huge amount is kinda relative...

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do here.  For one thing, 100k records is NOT huge.  I think you are talking about Classification because you are referring to categorical data points, so I'll focus on this, in the sample code below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from tpot import TPOTClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from pylab import rcParams
import seaborn as sb
import scipy
from scipy.stats import spearmanr

import sklearn
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
#from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import sklearn.metrics as sm

# import data from web
url = 'https://python-graph-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/mtcars.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)

# check for nulls
df.isnull().sum()


data = df.iloc[:,[2,10]].values
#data_names = ["drat","carb"]
y = df.iloc[:,[1]].values

# classification
y_predict = LogReg.predict(x)
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
report = classification_report(y,y_predict)
print(report)

# Result:


             precision    recall  f1-score   support

           4       0.91      0.91      0.91        11
           6       1.00      0.43      0.60         7
           8       0.78      1.00      0.88        14

    accuracy                           0.84        32
   macro avg       0.90      0.78      0.79        32
weighted avg       0.87      0.84      0.83        32

# continuing...
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, y,
                                                    train_size=0.75, test_size=0.25)


from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train,y_train)

predictions = lm.predict(X_test)

plt.scatter(y_test,predictions)



# find Best pipeline: 
# Fit the TPOT classifier 
tpot = TPOTClassifier(verbosity=2, max_time_mins=5, population_size=40)
tpot.fit(X_train, y_train)


# Final Result:

Best pipeline: RandomForestClassifier(SGDClassifier(FastICA(input_matrix, tol=0.6000000000000001), alpha=0.01, eta0=1.0, fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.75, learning_rate=invscaling, loss=modified_huber, penalty=elasticnet, power_t=0.1), bootstrap=False, criterion=entropy, max_features=0.45, min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=3, n_estimators=100)
Out[128]: 
TPOTClassifier(config_dict=None, crossover_rate=0.1, cv=5,
               disable_update_check=False, early_stop=None, generations=100,
               max_eval_time_mins=5, max_time_mins=5, memory=None,
               mutation_rate=0.9, n_jobs=1, offspring_size=None,
               periodic_checkpoint_folder=None, population_size=40,
               random_state=None, scoring=None, subsample=1.0, template=None,
               use_dask=False, verbosity=2, warm_start=False)
```

Comment: TPOT looks cool! Have you found it useful for projects with large datasets?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using CatBoost (CB)

CB can use **Categorical Variables** directly instead of using One Hot Encoding (which has a lot of problems.)

I'm not sure at what point it the number of levels becomes problematic, but there aren't that many car manufacturers, so I think you should be OK.  Even if you throw in "makes" (e.g. Chevy, Buick, etc from GM), it shouldn't be that bad.

CB is open source from Yandex.  https://catboost.ai